# Old math typographical style

Tags: fonts

a question amid history and curiosity. Do you know or recognize the font and math style used, for example, by the Journal of the American Statical Association [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2281806)? History because the style resembles in some way Computer Modern. Curiosity because it has its charm and would be nice to replicate with TeX.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: You can figure the fonts by looking at the Properties of the file in your PDF viewer. It is just Times, I think. Note that not everybody has access to JSTOR because of the paywall!

Comment: @cfr: I agree. I think, it's plain Times (not my favourite font ;-))

Comment: doesn't really look like times to me.  published in 1962, when it's just possible that monotype composition was still being used.  (don't know the practices of the asa.)  if so, it might be monotype 8a, the font on which computer modern was modeled.  @cfr -- if from the original, this would be a scan, and thus impossible to determine the font by checking the pdf properties.  check the shapes of the math "x" and "y" in [this article](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-074-01/S0002-9939-1979-0521863-4/S0002-9939-1979-0521863-4.pdf).  (i know for sure that was set with times.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton If it was scanned, it shouldn't list any fonts, though, should it? Or do you think the 4 it lists are just for the first page and the rest is scanned? Also, I can select text from e.g. the abstract which I wouldn't expect to be able to do with a scan.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The PDF you linked says that it uses Helvetica and TNR. Are you sure it is Times? They are similar, but there are differences between them as far as I know. At least, the Times Apple packaged in OS X could not be passed off as TNR unless the receiver was not really paying attention (or didn't actually care that much).

Comment: @cfr -- absolutely times.  produced on a harris fototronic from files prepared using the science typographers (sti) system, which used only times.  (note -- there are *many* times implementations, not all identical in small features.)  i'm surprised that the pdf says tnr -- i was certain this was scanned; i didn't think the original files were still usable, and they were certainly generated before pdf (or even ps) even existed.  could be that the abstract was redone for the e-distritution.  can you cut and paste from the body text?

Comment: It seems to me that the closest present-day approximation of the font in the linked article is OldStandard, which is shipped with relatively recent versions of texlive and can be used with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX and unicode-math.

Comment: @PavelRudnev -- just to be sure, the "linked article" you are referring to is the one linked in the question, from the journal of the american statistical association, not the one linked in my comment, from the proceedings of the american mathematical society.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I can copy text from the file linked in the question, yes. E.g. `An upper bound ontheerror introduced
 by considering
 only a finite
 number
of terms of the series willnow be established. The remainder
 after the first
n+ 1 terms ofthe seriesin (12) is givenby
A
Rn =
 -~ E
 -ED
 DmPm(#Z2).(5
4iraf m=n+l
 im .=o`. It doesn't do well copying the maths but that's not unusual and the text copies fine (if you ignore spacing issues which are also common). To be clear: *that* file says Times-Roman & Code2000. The PDF you linked: TNR and Helvetica. Agree about the different Times....

Comment: @cfr -- i thought you meant the file linked in *my* comment, which i am sure is a scan.  i didn't try to cut and paste from the file linked from the question.  it doesn't seem to be possible to cut and paste from the ams proceedings article, which i *know* to be scanned, and which, nonetheless, identifies fonts as helvetica and tnr (but there's an added line at the bottom of each page which dies appear to be helvetica, which could explain that).

Comment: I agree with @barbarabeeton: it's some Monotype font. The PDF properties most probably refer to fonts added in the postproduction after scanning the document.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Quite.

Comment: @egreg But if it were scanned, it would not be possible to copy text, would it?

Comment: @barbarabeeton `Abstract. A multiplication is constructed which extends the vector space structure of Euclidean n-space to a commutative algebra.` `The object of this paper is to present a multiplication which satisfies properties A, B, and D'. When n + 1 is prime, this multiplication approaches satisfying C and C in a manner to be made precise below. This multiplication is of particular interest due to its applications in the areas of pattern recognition and information processing.` `The paper proceeds by first constructing the algebra and its norm, then embedding it into Euclidean space.` ??

Comment: @barbarabeeton That is, I did mean the article linked in the question, but I also seem able to copy from both abstract and body of the article you linked to. This is very odd...?

Comment: @cfr I guess there's a layer obtained with OCR to make the text copyable to some extent.

Comment: @egreg I guess OCR has surely improved significantly, but barbara said that she could *not* copy text from that article.

Comment: @cfr -- barbara does not have ocr capability, at least not that she's aware of.  if you do, that could explain why we get different results.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Unless Okular has integrated it all of a sudden, I don't. I cannot normally copy text from scanned papers. However, if Okular has integrated it, that would be great! I remain somewhat sceptical, however, but I don't want to rule it out.

Comment: Thank you everyone! It is not for sure Times! The "OldStandard" font is completely new to me and it seems to be the right (or closest) font! Thanks @PavelRudnev for pointing out that! I guess that could be the answer.

Comment: Even though a similar integral sign seems to be difficult to find... what a pity, it's so incredibly charming!